# this expression is not working in python 2, only in python 3, how can i replace it in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

the accessing to the match result using error[2] is not possible in python 2

```
error=re.search(r"ticky: ERROR ([\w ]*) \((\w*)\)", line.strip())
if error is not None:
    error_dict[error[1]]=error_dict.get(error[1], 0)+1
    if error[2] not in entries_dict.keys():
        entries_dict[error[2]]= [0,0]
    entries_dict[error[2]][1]=+1
```

the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./ticky_check.py", line 22, in <module>
        if info[2] not in entries_dict.keys():
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the expression "error[2]" is not subscriptable, which means that the result of the `re.search()` function is not a list or tuple, and cannot be indexed by integer indices like arrays. Instead, you should use the `group()` method of the match object to extract the matching parts of the string.

Try replacing this code:

```py
if error[2] not in entries_dict.keys():
    entries_dict[error[2]]= [0,0]
entries_dict[error[2]][1]=+1
```

with this:

```py
error_part2 = error.group(2)
if error_part2 not in entries_dict.keys():
    entries_dict[error_part2]= [0,0]
entries_dict[error_part2][1]=+1
```

Ok, here is more readable for you:

```py
error_match = re.search(r"ticky: ERROR ([\w ]*) \((\w*)\)", line.strip())
if error_match is not None:
    error_message = error_match.group(1)
    error_dict[error_message] = error_dict.get(error_message, 0) + 1

    error_part2 = error_match.group(2)
    if error_part2 not in entries_dict.keys():
        entries_dict[error_part2] = [0, 0]

    entries_dict[error_part2][1] += 1
```